# Unity Button not shooting projectile properly

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab main character that moves around and shoots. I attached the prefab and the shoot function to a button on my canvas. When I start the game I can shoot fine, but once i start to move around the button keeps firing bullets from the same position. It doesn't recognize my character's transform moving and it doesn't recognize the position change. This functionality was working fine before I put it into a button, so I am assuming I am not correctly setting up the button.
[image: Here is my button set up, the prefab is in there, script shoot using the fire function]

Here is my fire function (The Offset transform is attached to my player, and in the prefab I have that transform attached to the script):

```
public Transform Offset;
public float Speed;

public void Fire()
{        
    GameObject obj = Pool.current.getObj();
    if (obj == null) return;

    obj.transform.position = Offset.position;
    obj.transform.rotation = Offset.rotation;
    obj.SetActive(true);            
}
```

Like i said this script worked fine when I wanted to use the space bar to shoot, but once I attached it to the button, it doesn't follow the players transform. Any Ideas?

Comment: Set the Offset to the transform of the player?

Comment: It doesn't recognize the players transform at all. I get the transform of the player in the start function of the script, I omitted this in the question, but either way it says the transform isnt there

Comment: What do you mean it isn't there? If it were null you would be getting exception. And if it's not there then why did you omit it in the question since the problem is clearly there?

Comment: Exactly that, i get an exception (unassigned reference exception for the variable i assigned to be the transform of the object). but the transform is there, only when i click the button for some reason it isn't getting recognized by my script

Comment: First... in Unity there can not be an object without a transform....
Second... I don't know why would you tie your character to be child of a button.... It would be better to create a variable of type UI.Button in your character script, assign the button in the inspector and in the start() method of your character do something like this:
myButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Fire();  });

Comment: @RobertoGuajardo Just tried this. I get an object refrence not a instance of an object error. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I don't follow. I suggest you edit your question to actually fit the problem. Currently your question says that the bullet always fires from the same place. It says nothing about unassigned reference exception. But the simple answer: the transform is not there and until you post the code to how you set the transform no one can really help you.

Comment: @FINDarkside i could have put transform.position instead of offset, it doesn't matter because it isn't recognizing either. that is what I was saying and since my object obviously has a transform I don't see a need to change my questio, because the fact remains the button wont notice this change in rotation or position...

Comment: did you assigned the button in the inspector? - also I just noticed a mistake on my side, since I told you to use a variable of type UI.Button, you only need to do: myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {Fire();});

Comment: It was not obvious that Offset is the transform of whatever the script is attached to. I thought it's the transform of the player. My second guess is that obj is null instead of the transform. You should still edit you question since the problem is the exception, not the starting point of your bullets.

Comment: @RobertoGuajardo that worked. thanks!

Comment: I will move it as an answer then :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create a variable of type UI.Button in your character script, assign the button in the inspector and in the start() method of your character or weapon do something like this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI

public Button myButton; //Assign in inspector

void Start()
{
myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => { Fire(); });
}
```

Above code will add the method Fire() as a listener of the OnClick() method of the button.